# Android EditText Not showing typed letters used for Filtering ListAdapter ListView

Tags: android, listview, filter, android-edittext

I have a `LinearLayout` with an `EditText` and a `ListView`.  I'm using the `EditText` to filter the `ListView`.  The filtering is working fine when I first show the screen and the soft keyboard automatically pops up.  As I type the typed letters do not show up in the `EditText`. If I tap on the `EditText`, the letters I type do show up but don't go to the filter.  It's as if there are 2 `EditText` there.

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:paddingBottom="6dip"
     android:paddingTop="4dip" >

     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/search_box"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
         android:inputType="text"
         android:maxLines="1"
         android:textSize="17dip" />

     <ListView
         android:id="@+id/beerListViewID"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="0dip"
         android:layout_weight="1" >

     </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's my set up for TextWatcher:

```
@Override public void onLoadFinished(Loader<ArrayList<BeerRecord>> loader,
        ArrayList<BeerRecord> beers) {
    // Set the new data in the adapter.
    ListView listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.beerListViewID);

    myAdapter = new BeerItemAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.beerline, beers);

    filterText = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.search_box);
    filterText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);

    listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

}
```

And the TextWatcher:

```
    private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {            
        myAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
    }

};
```

Should I post more code? Anyone have an idea why there would seem to be 2 `EditText`?

EDIT:  When the activity starts and the soft keyboard pops up, I can see that the viewable EditText does not have focus.  I must somehow be defining a second one that's hidden behind the first.

EDIT -- ANSWERED:
I figured it out. In the OnCreate method for this Fragment I had:

```
    getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.beer_listview);
```

I guess this was creating a second view. When I commented it out the 2nd EditText went away.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out, because the code that you had originally posted was correct. Anyway, you should put the "answered" edit as an answer and accept it to mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to reiterate from my comment above, now that 8 hours have passed.  I figured out what happened:

```
 getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.beer_listview);
```

was in my OnCreate for my fragment and it was putting another view on top of the "real" one.  I don't really know why, but I know commenting out fixed it.  I thought it was something like that and just searched for every reference I made to the view, commenting out as I went.

If someone wants to explain, feel free!